# How can I read multiple lines of a file into blocks in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file which contains the text below.

```
#L_ENTRY    <s_slash_1>
#LEX        </>
#ROOT       </>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <slash>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_comma_1>
#LEX        <,>
#ROOT       <,>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <comma>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_tilde_1>
#LEX        <~>
#ROOT       <~>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <tilde>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_at_1>
#LEX        <@>
#ROOT       <@>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <at>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>
```

I know how to make the lines into an array using Perl, but in this case I want to make an array with two elements. Each that begins with `#L_ENTRY` and ends with `#SYNONYM <0>`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please upload the text version of your file.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you have posted your data on a separate site and in image form. You should put all relevant question directly into the question if it is at all possible, and text (programs and data) should be added in text form so that it may be copied and used for testing a potential solution

Comment: My best guess about why you posted [another, identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525253/) is that you couldn't see how to edit your question to add the data in text form. If you look at the bottom of your post, just below the [perl] tag, there are four active links. The second one is `edit`, which allows you to edit your post. In future, please do that instead of opening a new question or writing data in comments. Thanks

Comment: Yes I am very new to programming and to this community, thank you very much for you kind explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.  Firstly, you can set the "input record separator" special variable (see more [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)).  In short, you are telling perl that a line is not terminated by a new-line char.  In your case, you could set it to '#SYNONYM <0>'.  Then when you read in one line, you get everything up to that point in the file that has that tag - if the tag is not there, then you get what's left in the file.  So, for input data that looks like this;

```
#L_ENTRY        <s_slash_1>
#LEX         </>
#ROOT        </>
#POS         <sp>
#SUBCAT      <slash>
#S_LINK            <>
#BITS     <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY        <s_comma_1>
#LEX         <,>
#ROOT        <,>
#POS         <sp>
#SUBCAT      <comma>
#S_LINK            <>
#BITS     <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>
```

if you run this;

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $filename = "data.txt" ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "$filename: $!" ;
local $/ = "#SYNONYM     <0>\n" ;
my @chunks = <$fh> ;
say $chunks[0] ;
say '---' ;
say $chunks[1] ;
```

You get;

```
#L_ENTRY        <s_slash_1>
#LEX         </>
#ROOT        </>
#POS         <sp>
#SUBCAT      <slash>
#S_LINK            <>
#BITS     <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

---

#L_ENTRY        <s_comma_1>
#LEX         <,>
#ROOT        <,>
#POS         <sp>
#SUBCAT      <comma>
#S_LINK            <>
#BITS     <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>
```

A couple of notes about this;

1. Any extra data between your records is going to "get caught in the net" and end up at the start of each record;
2. The record separator itself is still part of the data and is at the end of each record.

To get more control, it's better to process the data line-by-line and use regexs to switch between "capture" mode and "dont capture" mode:

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $filename = "data.txt" ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "$filename: $!" ;

my $found_start_token = qr/ \s* \#L_ENTRY \s* /x;
my $found_stop_token  = qr/ \s* \#SYNONYM \s+ \<0\> \s* \n /x;

my @chunks ;
my $chunk  ;
my $capture_mode = 0 ;

while ( <$fh> )  {
    $capture_mode = 1 if /$found_start_token/ ;
    $chunk .= $_ if $capture_mode ;
    if (/$found_stop_token/) {
        push @chunks, $chunk ;
        $chunk = '' ;
        $capture_mode = 0 ;
    }
}
say $chunks[0] ;
say '---' ;
say $chunks[1] ;
exit 0
```

A couple of notes;

1. The program works by string concatenation of the current line, `$_`, on to `$chunk` if we're in caputure mode.
2. Capture mode is turned off and on using regexs in 'extended mode', `/x`.  This allows adding whitespace to the regex for easier reading.
3. Extra data between record will *not* appear in the chunks.
4. It produces the same output as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the input record separator variable to the empty string, then perl will work in *paragraph mode*, and return a block at a time separated by one or more blank lines in the input data

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

local $/ = '';


my $n;
while ( <DATA> ) {
    printf "Block %d:\n<<%s>>\n\n", ++$n, $_;
}

__DATA__
A
B
C
D
E
F

A
B
C
D
E
F
```

#### output

```
Block 1:
<<A
B
C
D
E
F

>>

Block 2:
<<A
B
C
D
E
F

>>
```

Answer (score 0):

From this and [your succeeding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525253) it's looking like you have the answer but are unaware of it

As long as your blocks are separated by at least one blank line, you can use Perl's *paragraph mode*, which will hand you back the text in blocks

Here's another, different example that I hope you understand. I've created a file called `test.txt` that contains the data that you posted, and opened it in paragraph mode

The output is from [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), which I've used only to demonstrate that the resulting array contains exactly the four strings that you asked for

Please add a comment to this solution if you need any more explanation

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my $file = 'test.txt';

my @chunks = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    local $/ = '';
    <$fh>;
};

use Data::Dump;
dd \@chunks;
```

#### output

```
[
  "#L_ENTRY    <s_slash_1>\n#LEX        </>\n#ROOT       </>\n#POS        <sp>\n#SUBCAT     <slash>\n#S_LINK           <>\n#BITS    <>\n#WEIGHT      <0.1>\n#SYNONYM     <0>\n\n",
  "#L_ENTRY    <s_comma_1>\n#LEX        <,>\n#ROOT       <,>\n#POS        <sp>\n#SUBCAT     <comma>\n#S_LINK           <>\n#BITS    <>\n#WEIGHT      <0.1>\n#SYNONYM     <0>\n\n",
  "#L_ENTRY    <s_tilde_1>\n#LEX        <~>\n#ROOT       <~>\n#POS        <sp>\n#SUBCAT     <tilde>\n#S_LINK           <>\n#BITS    <>\n#WEIGHT      <0.1>\n#SYNONYM     <0>\n\n",
  "#L_ENTRY    <s_at_1>\n#LEX        <\@>\n#ROOT       <\@>\n#POS        <sp>\n#SUBCAT     <at>\n#S_LINK           <>\n#BITS    <>\n#WEIGHT      <0.1>\n#SYNONYM     <0>\n",
]
```