# how do I join multiple lines into one element of an array in PERL?

Tags: perl

```
#L_ENTRY    <s_slash_1>
#LEX        </>
#ROOT       </>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <slash>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_comma_1>
#LEX        <,>
#ROOT       <,>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <comma>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_tilde_1>
#LEX        <~>
#ROOT       <~>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <tilde>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>

#L_ENTRY    <s_at_1>
#LEX        <@>
#ROOT       <@>
#POS        <sp>
#SUBCAT     <at>
#S_LINK           <>
#BITS    <>
#WEIGHT      <0.1>
#SYNONYM     <0>
```

Above is my text file. I want to join each line into one element of an array until there is a 'return' and continue to join the next lines until there is another 'return'. In the text above, there are three returns, so what I want is an array of four elements.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes I have and I am still trying to find a way..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = "";
my @line;
my $el = '1';
while(<DATA>)
{
    if($_!~m/^$/i) {  $lines .= "$_\n"; }
    elsif($_=~m/^$/i) {
        $lines=~s/\n{1,}/\n/g;
    push(@line, "\n\n<array-$el>$lines</array-$el>"); $el++;  $lines = ""; }
}

print @line;
```

Comment: @Borodin: Ok Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can just read your file line by line. Since every line starty with an `#` there's a possibility to check whether it's empty or not.

Look at this:

```
my $yourFile = 'yourFile.txt';
open (my $data, '<', $yourFile) or die "Could not open $yourFile: $!";

my @output;
my $i = 0;
while( my $line = <$data>)  {   
  if( $line =~ /\#/){
    $output[$i] .= $line;
  }else{ 
   $i++;
  }
}
```

Here you read the file line by line. If there's an `#` you write the line in the array position `$i`. Otherwise you increment $i.